# Recurrences which involve polynomials with discriminant $d=11,19,43,67,163$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory, recurrence-relations, cubics

**Q:** *Which of these sequences, if any, can be grouped as similar or generalizations of each other?*

**Update 1**: Since a *ternary word or string* of length n is "a string of n characters where the characters are either 0, 1 or 2", then [$\color{red}{\text{A119826}}\,$](http://oeis.org/A119826) and [$\color{red}{\text{A255115}}\,$](http://oeis.org/A255115) are similar. That takes care of $d=67$ and $d=43$.

**Update 2:** For $d=19$, we have [A061279](http://oeis.org/A061279) for a *binary word*. Can we come up with a ternary version?

---

> **I.** $d = 163:\,$ Recurrence $a_n -6a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3}=0$

[A003731](http://oeis.org/A003731)  The number of Hamiltonian cycles in $C_5 \times P_n$

> **II.** $d = 67:\,$ Recurrence $a_n -2a_{n-1} -2a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3}=0$

[$\color{red}{\text{A119826}}\,$](http://oeis.org/A119826) Number of ternary words of length n with no 000's

[A181137](http://oeis.org/A181137) The number of ways to color n balls in a row with 3 colors with no color runs having lengths greater than 3

> **III.** $d = 43:\,$ Recurrence $a_n -2a_{n-1}  - 2a_{n-3}=0$

[A077999](http://oeis.org/A077999) Number of permutations on [n] that avoid nonconsecutive instances of the patterns 321 and 312

[$\color{red}{\text{A255115}}\,$](http://oeis.org/A255115) Number of n - length words on {0, 1, 2} in which 0 appears only in runs of length 2

> **IV.** $d = 19:\,$ Recurrence $a_n  - 2a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3}=0$

[A061279](http://oeis.org/A061279) Counts (binary) bit strings of length n in which no odd length block of 0's is followed by an odd length block of 1's

[A052907](http://oeis.org/A052907) Counts ordered walks of weight n on a single vertex graph containing 4 distinctly labelled loops of weights 2, 2, 3 and 3

[A107383](http://oeis.org/A107383) The number of maximal independent vertex sets (and minimal vertex covers) in the 2 X (n - 2) king graph

> **V.** $d = 11:\,$ Recurrence $a_n -2a_{n-1} + 2a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3}=0$

[A104767](http://oeis.org/A104767) Number of terms in the expansion of (x - 1)(x - 1)(x^2 - 1)(x^3 - 1) ...(x^F_n - 1), where F_n is the nth Fibonacci number

[A122788](http://oeis.org/A122788) (1, 3) - entry of the 3 X 3 matrix M^n, where M = {{0, -1, 1}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}

---

**P.S.** To elaborate, from the recurrence,

$$a_n -6a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} - 2a_{n-3}=0$$

we get the cubic characteristic equation,

$$x^3-6x^2+4x-2=0$$

the real root $x = 5.318628\dots$ of which is the *limiting ratio*. Incidentally,

$$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}} \approx x^{24}-24.00000000000000105\dots$$

Comment: See also this [related MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/288427/why-does-a-polynomial-with-discriminant-d-163-appear-in-this-sequence).