# The Heegner Polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, roots, recreational-mathematics

What is special about $x^3- 6 x^2 + 4 x -2$? The 24th power of the real root - 24 is curiously close to two other numbers, one being the [Ramanujan constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujanConstant.html).

[image: root 163]

There are more of these polynomials associated with the [Heegner numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HeegnerNumber.html).

[image: Heegner Polynomials]

**$poly_1 = x^2 -2$**.  The first root space has the [Pythagoras constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagorassConstant.html), [Silver ratio](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SilverRatio.html), vertices of an [octagon](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Octagon.html), A4 paper, [Ammann tile](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/AmmannTiles/) and the curiosity below, with numbers representing powers of $\sqrt2$.

[image: sqrt2 powers distance wheel]

**$poly_2 = x^3 - 2x^2 +2x-2$**.  The second root space is part of [tribonacci space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciConstant.html) $T = t^3 - x^2 -x-1$, notable for the [snub cube](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SnubCube.html). Roots $T_n$ as ${T_n}^2 - T_n$ are the roots of $poly_2$. The polynomial roots $1+2 T_n -{T_n}^2$, also in the same root space, become [de Weger's example](https://nitaj.users.lmno.cnrs.fr/abc.html#Ten%20algebraic%20abc), the second best known algebraic solution for the [ABC Conjecture](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/abcConjecture.html).

[image: snub cube]

**$poly_3 = x^3 - 2x-2$**. This root space builds the [12 point Heilbronn solution](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HeilbronnTrianglesInTheUnitSquare/) and the [12 disk covering solution](https://erich-friedman.github.io/packing/circovcir/). With $r$ as the real root, the circles have radius $\sqrt{(1,r,r^2)\cdot(-3,0,1)}$, with two centers on the $x$-axis at $\sqrt{(1,r,r^2)\cdot(-7,4,0)}$ and $\sqrt{(1,r,r^2)\cdot(-1,2,-1)}$.

[image: two twelves]

Can anyone find amazing properties for the root spaces of the last three polynomials?

These are related to [New Substitution Tilings Using 2, φ, ψ, χ, ρ](https://blog.wolfram.com/2019/03/07/shattering-the-plane-with-twelve-new-substitution-tilings-using-2-phi-psi-chi-rho/).

Comment: How does this anyway need to be placed in the combinatorics tag And by the way congrats for the 8k. Because the last (+1) is from me :-)

Comment: Undoubtedly you know all this. Just listing a few observations: The largest roots of the last three cubics are [Pisot numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pisot%E2%80%93Vijayaraghavan_number) explaining why their high powers are closer and closer to integers. Also the discriminants of those cubics have the corresponding Heegner number as a factor. Of course, that doesn't explain why the 24th power would be related to the Ramanujan constant.

Comment: Some remarks: (1) If $L$ is the splitting field of $x^3-6x^2+4x-2$ then $\text{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})\cong S_3$ and $L$ contains $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-163})$. (2) $L$ and all of its subfields have class number 1. (3) 24th powers have a rather special role in the land of modular forms (e.g. Dedekind eta function which is closely related to the j function).

These three observations are enough to convince me that it's not just a coincidence of finding a P.V. number whose powers happen to come close to the Ramanujan constant.

Comment: The real root of the cubic is
$$x=2+4 \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{15}{16}\sqrt{\frac{3}{2}}\right)\right)$$

Comment: OP has also posted this, on Brillhart's cubic $x^3-8x-10$ and $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}$: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2235113 – is there a simple relation between the two cubics?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes: $(x-2)^3-8(x-2)-10=x^3-6x^2+4x-2$

Answer (score 7):

Here is how to derive the approximation $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx x^{24}-24$.

First recall how the approximation $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx640320^3+744$ is proved.
The $j$ function has $q$-expansion
$$j(\tau)=\frac{1}{q}+744+196884q+21493760q^2+\cdots.$$
If we set $\tau=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{-163})$ and $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}=-e^{-\pi\sqrt{163}}$, then we have
$$-640320^3=j(\tau)=-e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}+744-\frac{196884}{e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}}+\frac{21493760}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{163}}}+\cdots.$$
This gives the approximation
$$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx640320^3+744.$$

For the approximation $e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx x^{24}-24$, we will use the Weber modular function
$$\mathfrak f(\tau)=q^{-1/48}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+q^{n-1/2}).$$
The $24$th power of $\mathfrak f(\tau)$ has $q$-expansion
$$\mathfrak f(\tau)^{24}=q^{-1/2}\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+q^{n-1/2})^{24}=q^{-1/2}+24+276q^{1/2}+2048q+11202q^{3/2}+\cdots.$$
If we set $\tau=\sqrt{-163}$ and $q=e^{2\pi i\tau}=e^{-2\pi\sqrt{163}}$, then we have
$$\mathfrak f(\sqrt{-163})^{24}=e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}+24+\frac{276}{e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}}+\frac{2048}{e^{2\pi\sqrt{163}}}+\frac{11202}{e^{3\pi\sqrt{163}}}+\cdots.$$
This gives the approximation
$$e^{\pi\sqrt{163}}\approx\mathfrak f(\sqrt{-163})^{24}-24.$$
The improved accuracy of this approximation is due to the fact that the coefficient $276$ is smaller than the coefficient $196884$.

The only remaining mystery is why $\mathfrak f(\sqrt{-163})$ is the real root of the cubic polynomial $x^3-6x^2+4x-2$.
One reference for this is the paper "On the Singular Values of Weber Modular Functions" by Yui and Zagier. From section 6 of the paper, we learn that there is a cubic polynomial
\begin{align*}
x^3-2\lambda x^2+2\mu x-2&=\left(x-\mathfrak f(\sqrt{-163})\right)\left(x-\frac{\sqrt2}{\mathfrak f\left(\frac{15+\sqrt{-163}}2\right)}\right)\left(x-\frac{\sqrt2}{\mathfrak f\left(\frac{-15+\sqrt{-163}}2\right)}\right)\\
&\approx(x-5.3186)(x-(0.3407+0.5099i))(x-(0.3407-0.5099i))
\end{align*}
with $\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb{Z}$ (this uses the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-163})$ has class number one).
Then expanding the right hand side shows that $\lambda=3$ and $\mu=2$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with exotic connections, sometimes it is helpful to take inspiration from Ramanujan. Thus, we'll bring in *q-continued fractions*, *pi formulas*, *nested radicals*, and *sequences*.

---

**I. *q*-Continued fractions**

Let $q = -e^{-\pi\sqrt{11}}.\,$  Then,

$$\frac{1}{T}+1 = \cfrac{(-q)^{-1/24}} {1 + \cfrac{q} {1-q + \cfrac{q^3-q^2} {1 + \cfrac{q^5-q^3} {1 + \cfrac{q^7-q^4} {1+\ddots}}}}}$$

where $T$ is the *tribonacci constant*. This is reminiscent of Ramanujan's cfracs which involve the *golden ratio*. And not surprisingly, the number $24$ appears again.

In general, for $q = -e^{-\pi\sqrt{n}}$ and positive integer $n$, then the cfrac is a radical usually of high degree for large $n$. However, for $n = (11,19,43,67,163),$

$$x_n=\cfrac{(-q)^{-1/24}} {1 + \cfrac{q} {1-q + \cfrac{q^3-q^2} {1 + \cfrac{q^5-q^3} {1 + \cfrac{q^7-q^4} {1+\ddots}}}}}$$

then $x_n$ is just the real root of the five cubics mentioned by Pegg, namely $x^3-2x^2+2x-2 = 0$, and the others.

---

**II. Pi formulas**

Given $v = x_{11} = \frac{1}{T}+1,$ where $T$ is still the tribonacci constant. Then,

$$\frac{1}{\pi} = \frac12\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(2k)!^3}{k!^6}\frac{(2v-1)(4v-3)k+(2v-1)(v-1)-\frac12}{v^{24k}}$$

Is that our friend the number $24$ again? In fact, similar pi formulas can be found using $x_n$ for $n = (11,19,43,67,163).$

---

**III. Nested radicals**

We have the well-known,

$$\phi =\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{1+\dots}}}}$$

with *golden ratio* $\phi$. The tribonacci version is,

$$\frac1{T-1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac12+\sqrt[3]{\frac12+\sqrt[3]{\frac12+\sqrt[3]{\frac12+\dots}}}}$$

Again, one can do the same for all cubic roots, but they may not be so pretty.

---

**IV. Sequences**

To avoid redundancy, more details can be found in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2565942/4781).